# solution of system of polynomials

Tags: polynomials, systems-of-equations

I have $3$ equations and $2$ unknowns $x,y$ as following:
$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
(\Delta_{11}*y^2 + \Delta_{12}*y + \Delta_{13})x^2 + (\Delta_{21}*y^2 + \Delta_{22}*y + \Delta_{23})x + \Delta_{31}*y^2 + \Delta_{32}*y + \Delta_{33} = 0 \\
(\Omega_{11}*y^2 + \Omega_{12}*y + \Omega_{13})x^2 + (\Omega_{21}*y^2 + \Omega_{22}*y + \Omega_{23})x + \Omega_{31}*y^2 + \Omega_{32}*y + \Omega_{33} = 0 \\
(\Gamma_{11}*y^2 + \Gamma_{12}*y + \Gamma_{13})x^2 + (\Gamma_{21}*y^2 + \Gamma_{22}*y + \Gamma_{23})x + \Gamma_{31}*y^2 + \Gamma_{32}*y + \Gamma_{33} = 0 \\
\end{array}
\right. 
$$
where $\Delta_{i,j}$, $\Omega_{i,j}$ and $\Gamma_{i,j}$ are known values. Is it possible to solve this system of equations for $x,y$?

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Yes, definitely. You can apply [Buchberger's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buchberger's_algorithm).

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I will check it. Is it in closed form?

Comment: You have an [_overdetermined system_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overdetermined_system) (has more equations than unknowns). It almost always has no solution when constructed with random coefficients.

Answer (score 0):

HINT.-When you have a linear system in $x^2, x$ such as
$$\begin{cases}A_1x^2+A_2x+A_3=0\\B_1x^2+B_2x+B_3=0\\C_1x^2+C_2x+C_3=0\end{cases}$$ you can see it as a system in three unkowns $x^2,x,w$ so you have
$$\begin{pmatrix}A_1&A_2&A_3\\B_1&B_2&B_3\\C_1&C_2&C_3\end{pmatrix}\cdot\begin{pmatrix}x^2\\x\\w\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}$$

Now, since you have the obvious solution $(0,0,0)$ besides of the main solutions the solution of this system is not unique hence the determinant of the matrix of coefficients must be equal to $0$.

This gives a polynomial equation in $y$ of degree $6$.After solving this equation you have for each root a quadratic equation giving the corresponding values of $x$.

Comment: thank you. I will check it. but why there is an additional $\omega$?

Comment: It is a kind of artifice. Otherwise you can "have it in your memory" as a condition of compatibility of three linear equations with two unknowns.

Comment: He is looking to solve for $x$ ***and*** $y$. Where is the $y$ in this solution?